# Cannot get images from webpage with high resolution using BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a link that contains computer games and for each game I want to extract the image of the product **with the highest resolution** and not all img tags. So far I have:

```
#GET ALL IMG TAGS
img_tags = soup2.find_all('img')
#CREATE LIST WITH IMG TAGS
urls_img = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]
#CHECK EACH IMG TAG
for murl in urls_img:
    filename = re.search(r'/([\w_-]+[.](jpg|png))$', murl)
    if filename is not None:
        with open(filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
            if 'http' not in murl:
                murl = '{}{}'.format(site, murl)
                #GET THE RESPONSE OF IMG URL
            response = requests.get(murl)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Then, what is the problem? Getting images? Getting images with high resolution (as the title suggests)? Getting images with the highest resolution (as the body of your question suggests)? Do you get errors? Do you get nothing?

Comment: can you provide the start url please?

Comment: @QHarr http://zegetron.gr/b2b/product-category/pc/?products-per-page=all contains the list of the games

Comment: what value determines high resolution?

Comment: over 500 px I guess, some of them have 2-3 images but one of them is at least over 500

Comment: looks like you have to gather all img links and filter on highest px for each set of links per img?

Comment: Yes instead of downloading 4-5 imgs and then delete them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191782/discussion-between-nikos-and-qharr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Following discussion, the following gets the initial product urls, excluding placeholders, and visits each page looking for the largest image. The largest image have an attribute `['data-large_image']`.

I use `Session` for efficiency with re-using connection.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'http://zegetron.gr/b2b/product-category/pc/?products-per-page=all'
images = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    product_links = [item.select_one('a')['href'] for item in soup.select('.product-wrapper') if item.select_one('[src]:not(.woocommerce-placeholder)')]

    for link in product_links:
        r = s.get(link)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        images.append(soup.select_one('[data-large_image]')['data-large_image'])
```

---

Former answer (based on original single url with all products):

Try the following which looks for the `srcset`  attribute in each listing. If present it takes the last `src` link listed (as they are ordered by ascending resolution), otherwise, the `src` attribute is taken.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('http://zegetron.gr/b2b/product-category/pc/?products-per-page=all')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
listings = soup.select('.thumb-wrapper')
images = []

for listing in listings:
    link = ''
    if listing.select_one(':has([srcset])'):
        links = listing.select_one('[srcset]')['srcset']
        link = links.split(',')[-1]
        link = link.split(' ')[1]
    else:
        if listing.select_one('[src]:not(.woocommerce-placeholder)'):
            link = listing.select_one('img[src]')['src']
    if link:
        images.append(link)
print(images)
```

Comment: Cant't I access the img_tags attrs and check if width is over 500?

Comment: Don't you want the largest of all available images? And yes that might be an approach. My approach also looks for largest and excludes placeholders I think.

Comment: just open the image on browser and examine the common attribute or class. for class:
soup.select_one('.<classname>')

Answer (score 1):

I found that this maybe is easier and solved my question

```
for each_img_tag in img_tags:
    width = each_img_tag.get('width')
    if width is not None and int(width)>500:
        urls_img.append(each_img_tag['src'])
```

even though I dont know if it is faster or not

Comment: isn't this only asking for images over a certain size as opposed to the largest resolution available for any given image?

Comment: Yes but in your case you get the images from the product list URL http://zegetron.gr/b2b/product-category/pc/?products-per-page=all , but I use the list only for the product URL, which I open and then from the opened URL I try to get the images.

Comment: @QHarr If I run the code you suggest it is very fast but I get img url with 200x285 resolutions etc not img url with 800x600

Comment: Yes, I open one by one the 35 links and get the images per product which are with width >500 about 112 files with several 600x750 600x875 which are not thumbnails